# how to call below class using trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

```
public class contactCreation{
    integer i;
    list<contact> conlist = new list<contact>();

    public void createContacts(list<contact> contacts){

        for(i=0; i<=20; i++){
            contact c = new contact(lastname = 'contact'+i);
            conlist.add(c);
        }
        insert conlist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just some observations.  You don't seem to be using the list of contacts you are passing into your method so its really not necessary.  All this class does is create 21 new contacts and inserts them, no relation to the list you pass in.  Is this on purpose?  Also, as you don't seem to have a constructor, might as well make this method static so there's no need to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Trigger XY on WHATEVER (before/after ACTION)
{
    List<Contact> yourListOfContacts = // generate a list of contacts
    ContactCreation aContactCreationInstance = new ContactCreation();
    aContactCreationInstance.createContacts(yourListOfContacts);
}
```